# Recovering a partial PostgreSQL archive

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

I have $PGDATA/base but nothing else.  It was taken from an installation after the postgreSQL service was shutdown, so is clean.  Is there any way to recreate the other elements in $PGDATA that allow it to be used again - pg_tblspc/, global/ ?

FWIW I am running 8.1.23.

Thanks

Comment: No. You're going to have to restore from a backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left out so much that your chances of recovering useful data are negligible.

- `pg_clog` contains the commit/rollback logs. Without these, the system doesn't know which parts of the database files are valid and which are not. (gross oversimplification, but hey).
- `pg_xlog`, the write-ahead logs. Without these, the database can't handle incomplete writes, so it'll see the database files in an incomplete state that might be damaged. Indexes may be corrupt, heap pages might be partially written, etc.
- `global/pg_control`, the file that contains the system identifier, transaction wrap-around value, transaction log checkpoint position, and a whole lot more.

... and more.

It is vital to *follow the instructions in the documentation on how to back up a database*. Failure to follow the instructions will result in a useless, unrecoverable backup. Testing backups is also vital.

With in-depth analysis and a hacked version of the `postgres` server binary that was modified for data recovery I expect it *might* be possible to recover a corrupted version of your data, with duplicate entries in primary keys, broken foreign keys, multiple copies of data that was updated, reappearing deleted rows, etc. This would require some in-depth knowledge of the PostgreSQL server and take some significant time - so you'd be looking at a non-trivial cost and you'd only get back a mangled copy of your data.

Comment: Fair point. I didn't ever say that it was a backup.  The truth is that $PGDATA/base was relocated onto a large disk, and then the disk with the rest of $PGDATA was lost.  This strategy is obviously seriously flawed!

Comment: Incredibly so; what should've been done instead is to use *tablespaces* to relocate data appropriately. Anyway - I hope you have backups, because you're going to need them. If you don't, see http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/ - but be aware that you'll need people with serious knowledge of PostgreSQL's source code to have any hope of helping, and it'll take them a fair bit of time and therefore $$ to reconstruct even a badly damaged version of your data.